# Ado.Net - Execute Scalar : capture return as integer or string or boolean

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

Below was recommended to use in case string is returned from scalar

```
Dim lJobName as String = String.Empty
Dim oJobName as object = SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()

If oJobName Is Nothing Then
    'Do something with the error condition
Else
    lJobName = oJobName.ToString
End If
```

How can I make a generic function which will help me to trap other data types also (so execute scalar - can return integer or boolean or string

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. `ExecuteScalar` will always return `Object`, and it's up to you to `CAST` in to another datatype.

- [**SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

Comment: Yes, you are correct - it returns object. Can you please advice how can I cast it to integer or string or boolean

Comment: @ConradJagger if you want to cast it as string, `lJobName = (string)oJobName`, or as int `lJobName = (int)oJobName`